# firefox makes request twice randomly

Tags: php, session, firefox, cookies, header

I realized using my site that Firefox makes a URL request twice... randomly.

Yes, it' s weird, but I don't know how to deal with it.

The problem is as follow:

The first my php code do is to regenerate ssid

then save new cookies, etc..

When Firefox makes two request at the very begining it's like the first PHP call is executed, but the response is omitted, so the request is made again and the ssid is different so the session is lost

I realized of that because both requests appears on the network log in debug panel.
The first request has no "status" and no response headers... so is executed but omitted...

any help?

Comment: Impossible to say without any code. When you say Firefox you mean ONLY Firefox ? Did you try on any other browser ?

Comment: yes, only with firefox. I've tried with other browsers but never happened. right now i'm trying to reproduce it but it's working fine. if I got it I will take a snapshot

Comment: Please post relevant snippets of your code and, at least, a minimum working example.